# Which probiotics can exist in beer and at what abv's?

Tags: beer, open-fermentation

Just curious which specific strains can exist in beer, and if so, what are the various alcoholic thresholds for each?

Answer (score 2):

Pathogens have a hard time surviving very long in finished beer let alone probiotics.

Most open fermentation bacteria (lacto, pedio) die off pretty quickly once yeasts have produced alchohol.

Further even antibiotics are adversely affected even by consuming alchohol while on them.

There are many articles on how habitually consuming a lot of alcohol can deplete the bowel of probiotics.

So I would say beer of any normal strength ABV wouldn't be a good medium for probiotics to survive in.

The low pH and hops in beer also play a big role, in inhibiting bacteria growth and survivability in beer.

Comment: Your second statement about bacteria dying off is incorrect.  If this was true repitching the slurry from beers with lacto, pedio and sacc would come out clean and characteristic of just the sacc.  Which we know is not true.  These organisms go dormant at a certain level of ABV, but they do not entirely die off.

Comment: @brewchez I wasn't saying those bacteria die just from the ABV, they die off in beer at that general point in time of fermentation. Many things play a role in beer that make it a difficult medium. A lot of probiotics have mediums with alcohol, kombucha for example. His question is beer a good medium, which it is not. So I guess from your comment, all we need to do is pitch wort with a fresh bottle of lambic to make a lambic that's only ever been able to be produced in Senne Valley.

Comment: on a side note ... its believed yeast evolved to synthesize alcohol as an offensive mechanism in order to fight off bacteria as the both compete to consume the sugars of rotting fruits